Missing = inserted for \ifnum, for real
I have my tex code here and receive not a compilation error, just an error, the code is still working but ignoring the case. I wanted to make some edges green, but it does not work.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.23][>=latex]

\draw[step=1,white!40!gray, very thin] (0,-10) grid (64,10);
\draw[black, ->, thick] (0,-12) -- (0,12) node [above] {$d_\phi(u)$};
\draw[black, ->, thick] (0,0) -- (65,0) node [right] {$u$};% node [midway, below] {\large 001000101110001000100010111000101110111011100010};
\draw[red, thick] (0,-2) -- (64,-2);
\xdef\dphi{0};
\xdef\i{0};
\foreach \a in {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,  0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1}
{   
    \xdef\i{\i+1};
    \if \a 0
        \draw[blue,thick] (\i - 1, \dphi) -- (\i, \dphi+2);
        \xdef\dphi{\dphi+2};
        \node[blue] (\i) at (\i-0.5,-7) {\small \a};
    \fi
    \if \a 1
        \ifnum \dphi = 1
            \draw[green,thick] (\i - 1, \dphi) -- (\i, \dphi-3);
        \else
            \draw[blue,thick] (\i - 1, \dphi) -- (\i, \dphi-3);
        \fi
        \xdef\dphi{\dphi-3};
        \node[blue] (\i) at (\i-0.5,-7) {\small \a};
        
    \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}

But I think the syntax is fine, since if I change \ifnum \dphi 1 to \ifnum \a 1, then it works perfectly. I guess it does not work because of some variables' types shenanigans. I just started to learn how to use variables in tex and tikz, so extra materials would be appreciated


[scale=0.23][>=latex] should be changed into [scale=0.23,>=latex]
The semicolons (;) after \xdef should be deleted.


thanks, it does not solve the problem though(

Welcome! \xdef\i{} Never do this. How sure are you that nothing else you need defines \i at any time? But the problem is that \dphi isn't a number, whereas \a is.

I don't know why you say you don't get a compilation error. Compilation fails with an error. Isn't that the definition?

If you want to use \ifnum to compare \dphi with anything alse, you have to define \dphi as a 

There are complation errors which stop compilation and give you no pdf, and some errors which just there. How to do define smth as number?

In plain TeX, you can use \newcount. In latex format, you can use \newcounter.

If it gives you a PDF after an error it is because you've told it to carry on regardless. That's fine, but the result is only good for debugging. (Overleaf does this by default.)

I am not sure that understood the syntax, but I still can't figure it out. Should I add \newcounter at the beginning of the code?

@Vesch Put \newcounter in your preamble.

The main problem is that \dphi is not a number. It works for \a because \a is a number. You can use a counter and \value{} when comparing.
A second problem is that \xdef\i{} globally overwrites a command which is very probably already defined. Never do \xdef\anything{} unless certain \anything doesn't exist. In doubt, test first.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
% example uses neither library?
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcounter{dphi}
% \newcommand\i{}% would tell you \i is already defined
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.23,>=latex]
  
  \draw[step=1,white!40!gray, very thin] (0,-10) grid (64,10);
  \draw[black, ->, thick] (0,-12) -- (0,12) node [above] {$d_\phi(u)$};
  \draw[black, ->, thick] (0,0) -- (65,0) node [right] {$u$};% node [midway, below] {\large 001000101110001000100010111000101110111011100010};
  \draw[red, thick] (0,-2) -- (64,-2);
  \setcounter{dphi}{0}
  \foreach \a [count=\i from 1] in {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,  0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1}
  {   
    \ifnum\a=0
      \draw[blue,thick] (\i - 1, \value{dphi}) -- (\i, \value{dphi}+2);
      \addtocounter{dphi}{2}
      \node[blue] (\i) at (\i-0.5,-7) {\small \a};
    \fi
    \if \a 1
      \ifnum\value{dphi}=1
        \draw[green,thick] (\i - 1, \value{dphi}) -- (\i, \value{dphi}-3);
      \else
        \draw[blue,thick] (\i - 1, \value{dphi}) -- (\i, \value{dphi}-3);
      \fi
      \addtocounter{dphi}{-3}
      \node[blue] (\i) at (\i-0.5,-7) {\small \a};
    \fi
  }
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}



It does not really solve it, since I am still struggling. I don't know how use counters, 20 minutes of googling and testing was not enough. What is the exact syntax or where can i find it? And there is no easier way, to use variables and etc, isn't it? I mean \x = \y + 2 instead of  setcounter{\x}{value{\y}+2}.

@Vesch Any introduction to LaTeX should explain how to use counters. But there's really only 4 commands: \newcounter{mycounter}, \setcounter{mycounter}{26}, \addtocounter{mycounter}{2} and \stepcounter{mycounter}. There's also a variant for cross-references, but that's not relevant here. LaTeX relies on these everywhere: for enumerate and for counting things (sections, equations, pages). If it is an integer, it's probably a counter. These are wrappers around the underlying TeX structures. You could use a TeX count instead, but you'd still need \value etc.

I know about counters for enumerate and etc, but never use them as variables for some pseudocoding. I end up making a working version, so thank you

@Vesch Sure there are easier ways within PGF/TikZ. There's tikzmath and pgfmath etc. But \ifnum isn't pgfmath. So it doesn't do what pgfmath does. It requires numbers and nothing else. If it were pgfmath, it would do its best to interpret your input as a number. Then you don't need to be so careful. (But it is much slower, of course.) But if you use LaTeX, you need to learn what counters are regardless. Really, that is a very basic thing to know.

@Vesch You can probably write \thedphi in place of \value{dphi} when pgfmath (as opposed to TeX) is doing the parsing. As I say, pgfmath is much more forgiving.

Sorry, but the syntax is not fine. If \dphi is, say, 0, then \xdef\dphi{\dphi+2} is the same as
\gdef\dphi{0+2}

and no arithmetic is performed. So at the next stage, doing again \xdef\dphi{\dphi+2} will be the same as
\gdef\dphi{0+2+2}

Whilel using such definition of \dphi in coordinates is fine, because TikZ will do the arithmetic, you can't do \ifnum\dphi=2 because
\ifnum0+2=2

is illegal.
What you want is
\xdef\dphi{\inteval{\dphi+2}}

Not to mention that if you use something naïf after the (fixed) code you'll get a big surprise:

(there will be a lot more +1 in the actual output).

the start should be \begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.23,>=latex]

no semicolon should follow \xdef\dphi{...}

counting the cycles is provided by TikZ

spaces should be avoided in the list for \foreach


\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=0.23,>=latex]
\draw[step=1,white!40!gray, very thin] (0,-10) grid (64,10);
\draw[black, ->, thick] (0,-12) -- (0,12) node [above] {$d_\phi(u)$};
\draw[black, ->, thick] (0,0) -- (65,0) node [right] {$u$};
\draw[red, thick] (0,-2) -- (64,-2);
\xdef\dphi{0}
\foreach \a [count=\i from 1] in {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,%
  0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,%
  0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1}{   
    \if \a 0
        \draw[blue,thick] (\i - 1, \dphi) -- (\i, \dphi+2);
        \xdef\dphi{\inteval{\dphi+2}}
        \node[blue] (\i) at (\i-0.5,-7) {\small \a};
    \fi
    \if \a 1
        \ifnum \dphi = 1
            \draw[green,thick] (\i - 1, \dphi) -- (\i, \dphi-3);
        \else
            \draw[blue,thick] (\i - 1, \dphi) -- (\i, \dphi-3);
        \fi
        \xdef\dphi{\inteval{\dphi-3}}
        \node[blue] (\i) at (\i-0.5,-7) {\small \a};
    \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}

naïf

\end{document}


